# Warning: pointer of type 'void *' used in subtraction

Tags: c

Although it runs correctly, the following results in the aforementioned compiler warning:

```
return ((item - (my->items))/(my->itemSize));
```

'item' is a 'void *'; 'my->items' is a 'void *'; 'my->itemSize' is an 'int'

Casting 'item' and 'my->items' as an 'int *' caused the program to run improperly.  What is the best way to remove the warning?

Comment: as a general rule of thumb, do not use untyped (void*) variables...

Comment: I understand that, but I am using void * because I am trying to implement a general structure

Comment: I personally prefer `return (item - my->items) / my->itemSize;` (2 less parentheses pairs), but it's not really important.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Additions and subtractions with pointers work with the size of the pointed type:

```
int* foo = 0x1000;
foo++;
// foo is now 0x1004 because sizeof(int) is 4
```

Semantically speaking, the size of `void` should be zero, since it doesn't represent anything. For this reason, pointer arithmetic on `void` pointers should be illegal.

However, for several reasons, `sizeof(void)` returns 1, and arithmetic works as if it was a `char` pointer. Since it's semantically incorrect, you do, however, get a warning.

To suppress the warning, use `char` pointers.

Comment: I generally feel happier about `unsigned char *` as a raw data element in C than `char *` which hints at things being an C style string.  Other wise this is a perfect answer.

Comment: It would have been helpful if C had defined a "blob of bits" type that could access memory like `char`, but wouldn't be an integer type.  Use of `char*` for such purposes could have been deprecated in favor of a proper "bag of bits" type, and sandboxing implementations would have been able to offer much stronger guarantees than are possible with code that can do arithmetic on raw bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Cast to a `char *`:

```
return ((char *)item - (char *)my->items)/my->itemSize);
```

Since `char` is size of 1 byte, you will get the value you are expecting vs your `int *` pointer example which calculates how many `int`s are between the two address. That's how pointer arithmetic works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing aritmethical operations in a pointer, I wonder how is that running properly.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with pointer arithmetic, I misread the code and thought he was doing normal math, not pointer. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do normal arithmetic, you have to dereference the pointer (e.g. `*item`).  If you're trying to do pointer arithmetic, the pointer has to be of a type, like `char*` or `int*` (otherwise the compiler won't know how much to increment by).